# Convert timestamp to time gives the wrong time

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, unix-timestamp

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I've got a timestamp (long), and am trying to change it to a readable format.

Here's the timestamp:
`1404162530517`

When I verify the time using epoch converter, it says it is 5:08PM (correct)

When I try and use my code to parse it, it says 10:21PM (wrong)

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
long unixSeconds = Long.parseLong(tstamp);  
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date); 

SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "hh:mma ", Locale.ENGLISH);
timeDate = timeFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(tstamp);
System.out.println(timeDate);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so your in the timezone EDT. However, the Unix timestamp is counted from the Unix epoch *in UTC*. In other words, you are 5 hours behind UTC, and so the timestamp is 5 hours off since it's counting from midnight 1970 in UTC.

So how do you fix this? In your first `SimpleDateFormat`, put that the input timezone is UTC. That should convert UTC to your time (EDT):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Just a minor fix/advise: Use "UTC" instead of "Etc/UTC", latter is deprecated and uses for offsets not equal to zero reversed signs.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Fixed that. Thanks. I knew something in that world was depreciated, but I wasn't exactly sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dividing your timestamp by 1000? by default the correct timestamp is only 10 digits I guess.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that

Comment: awesome! have a great day